# PHP: Adding space to a string with lowercaseUppercase scenario including numbers

Tags: php, regex

I have a string:

> Baths: 2 full, 1 **halfBuilt in 1990Views** since listing: **1,845All time views**: 2,00013 shoppers saved this **homeHOA Fee:** $399/moLaundry: **In UnitParking:** Carport, Garage - Detached, 2 spaces, **314 sqftLast** sold: Apr 2011

I'm trying to make the above string more readable - so if you noticed there are no spaces in between new information. I have bold the above areas. What I noticed though is it ends with a smaller case letter then new information starts with an upper case.

Example: `halfBuilt` or `1,845All`, etc. So my idea to make this readable is to add space in between them. So how do we do this in php and maybe regex? Thanks!

Comment: What is the scenario that you want spaces on? Lowercase letters run into uppercase, and alpha next to numbers? Maybe... `([a-z\d]+)([A-Z])`? with `$1 $2`.

Comment: the best would be all scenarios

Comment: Can we roll this back to see the bold type?

Comment: But upon inspecting all the strings I notices that [numbers]Uppercase for some instances aside from the lowerUpper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to break when letters/numbers run into an Uppercase letter. If that is this case this work:

```
/([a-z\d]+)([A-Z])/
```

Regex 101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/wV8eI6/1

PHP Usage:

```
$string = "Baths: 2 full, 1 **halfBuilt in 1990Views** since listing: **1,845All time views**: 2,00013 shoppers saved this **homeHOA Fee:** $399/moLaundry: **In UnitParking:** Carport, Garage - Detached, 2 spaces, **314 sqftLast** sold: Apr 2011";
$regex = '/([a-z\d]+)([A-Z])/';
echo preg_replace($regex, '$1 $2', $string);
```

Output:

> Baths: 2 full, 1 **half Built in 1990 Views** since listing: **1,845 All time views**: 2,00013 shoppers saved this **home HOA Fee:** $399/mo Laundry: **In Unit Parking:** Carport, Garage - Detached, 2 spaces, **314 sqft Last** sold: Apr 2011

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/501264

Comment: what if I wanted to add a newline/linebreak instead of a space?

Comment: Use `\n` in place of the space; or if in a browser `<br>`. e.g. `'$1\n$2'` or `'$1<br>$2'`

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
$string = preg_replace("/([a-z0-9])([A-Z])/", "$1 $2", $string);

echo $string;
// => "Baths: 2 full, 1 half Built in 1990 Views since listing: 1,845 All time views: 2,00013 shoppers saved this home HOA Fee: $399/mo Laundry: In Unit Parking: Carport, Garage - Detached, 2 spaces, 314 sqft Last sold: Apr 2011"
```