# Add spaces to string

Tags: php, loops

How to add space after n characters in a string?

I have to format phone numbers to Swiss format:
0700000000 to become 070 000 00 00

So it has to be like a loop after 3 characters then 7 then 10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Adding space to a string with lowercaseUppercase scenario including numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750489/php-adding-space-to-a-string-with-lowercaseuppercase-scenario-including-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop. You can use a simple [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) and then [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) to put it back into a string, separated by a space.

```
echo implode(" ", preg_split("/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})/", "0700000000", -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE) );
```

https://eval.in/684950